# What function is the expression $\sum^\infty_{n=2} \frac{nz^n}{(n-2)!}$ a representation of?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

I would like to express $\sum^\infty_{n=2} \frac{nz^n}{(n-2)!}$ in terms of of some well known function, say $e^z,\cos z ....$ etc.

I have tried differentiating, as well as integrating term by term, but I cannot spot a clear pattern. I suspect that this can be written "in terms of" $e^z$, but cannot see how to get there.

Comment: Reindex the summation so it starts at zero and pull out z^2

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I appreciate the suggestion. I got $z^2\sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{(n+2)z^{n}}{n!}$, but I am still stuck. How do I handle the $(n+2)$?

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} z^k = k z^{k-1}$ and $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2} z^k = k(k-1) z^{k-2}$ will probably help.

Comment: You can also try $\frac{(n+2)z^{n}}{n!}= \frac{nz^{n}}{n!}+ \frac{2z^{n}}{n!}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty.

\begin{align*}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{nz^n}{(n-2)!}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n+2)z^{n+2}}{n!}\\&=z^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{nz^n}{n!}+2z^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}\\&=z^3\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+2z^2e^z\\&=z^3e^z+2z^2e^z\\&=e^zz^2(z+2)
\end{align*}

The index in the third equality could be changed to start from $n=1$ because in the previous line, for $n=0$, the term was just $0$ and hence could be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Write

(n/(n - 2)!)*z^n

as

-((n^2 z^n)/n!) + (n^3 z^n)/n!

and express both terms as

-z d/dz (z  d/dz (z^n/n!))

and

z d/dz (z d/dz (z  d/dz (z^n/n!))).

Then calulate the same derivatives of Exp[z]  to get

E^z (2 + z)  z^2

Comment: please use latex

Comment: Please format your math with MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).